# получение данных с удаленного апи на локалхост через фетч

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, fastapi

Я работаю на локалхосте над веб-приложением на реакте + тайпскрипт. Бэк на FastApi коллеги подняли, я могу получать данные вставляя урл реквест в строке браузера, но пытаясь получать данные через фетч в приложении я ловлю ошибку корс.

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://*****/offset=0&limit=15'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Я понимаю, что дело в заголовке Access-Control-Allow-Origin. На моках типа dummyJSON в этом заголовке стоит просто *, которая позволяет собственно все источники. В нашем случае этот заголовок не указан. Как мне работать с бэком? Нужно, чтобы локалхост внесли как источник?

Я пробовал режим no-cors, но ловлю 405.

Почему же я могу тогда через браузер получать данные?

АПД. Смог получить данные после установки [расширения для хрома](https://mybrowseraddon.com/access-control-allow-origin.html), но что-то мне подсказывает, что это не очень хороший подход.

Comment: Когда запускаешь реакт-приложение, что у тебя написано в командной строке браузера?

Comment: Если имеется в виду консоль, то там пара ошибок: 

Access to fetch at 'https:/*****/?offset=0&limit=15' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Затем
https://**********/story/?offset=0&limit=15 net::ERR_FAILED 200

Comment: Не консоль. Там где УРЛ страниц пишут. Там у тебя `localhost:3000` используется?

Comment: Понял. В адресной строке localhost:3000

Comment: Замени `localhost` на ИП-адрес `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: сделал, ничего не поменялось. Видимо, нужно поговорить с бекером

Answer (score 1):

Самым правильным решением будет добавить  хост вашего фронтенда в ориджин на бэке. Но это только на время разработки, так как по итогу у вас бэк и фронт будут на одном домене.
Пример взят из официальной документации по FastAPI:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors 
import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


@app.get("/")
async def main():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```